# Facebook / Graph API - How do I embed a SWF in a wall post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've found a lot of conflicting or outdated information and most of the links to fb's doc's are broken. Is it possible to embed a swf (eg, a game) in a wall post? Does the domain still need to be white listed? Is swf embedding part of the open graph meta tags? If this is still possible, what are the prerequisites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use og:video with swf from opengraph dynamically on your page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

then anytime the page is liked - the swf is embedded on the user's wall. the app is not needed to be whitelisted for that.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this. Do you know if its strictly for videos? I heard rumors some apps are posting full blown games, but I can't confirm this.

Comment: Any valid swf should technically work but the user has to click it to start playing.